# How can you generate a Vue component for each level of a nested JSON object when you don't know how many there will be?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have some JSON data that contains a list of retailers and some of these retailers have subretailers that can go many levels deep.

I would like to use Vue to generate markup that will display the parent retailer and then the nested subretailers below it similar to this:

[image]

I would like to create a function that will accommodate for as many nested retailers as there are in the JSON. Here is what the JSON looks like:

```
    [{
      "RetailerChilderen":[

      ],
      "Id":83107,
      "Name":"10-11",
      "HasInsightsCenter":true,
      "ParentId":0,
      "UserSelected":true,
      "UserHasAccess":true,
      "Letter":"#",
      "IsVisible":true,
      "InDepthLevel":0
   },
   {
      "RetailerChilderen":[

      ],
      "Id":82800,
      "Name":"1-800-Flowers.com",
      "HasInsightsCenter":false,
      "ParentId":0,
      "UserSelected":true,
      "UserHasAccess":true,
      "Letter":"#",
      "IsVisible":true,
      "InDepthLevel":0
   },
   {
      "RetailerChilderen":[
         {
            "RetailerChilderen":[
               {
                  "RetailerChilderen":[

                  ],
                  "Id":82371,
                  "Name":"Hervis Sports",
                  "HasInsightsCenter":false,
                  "ParentId":82247,
                  "UserSelected":false,
                  "UserHasAccess":false,
                  "Letter":null,
                  "IsVisible":true,
                  "InDepthLevel":0
               }
            ],
            "Id":82247,
            "Name":"Spar Austria",
            "HasInsightsCenter":false,
            "ParentId":648,
            "UserSelected":false,
            "UserHasAccess":false,
            "Letter":null,
            "IsVisible":true,
            "InDepthLevel":0
         },
         {
            "RetailerChilderen":[
               {
                  "RetailerChilderen":[

                  ],
                  "Id":655,
                  "Name":"Despar Italy",
                  "HasInsightsCenter":false,
                  "ParentId":83095,
                  "UserSelected":false,
                  "UserHasAccess":false,
                  "Letter":null,
                  "IsVisible":true,
                  "InDepthLevel":0
               },
               {
                  "RetailerChilderen":[

                  ],
                  "Id":82250,
                  "Name":"Spar Slovenia",
                  "HasInsightsCenter":false,
                  "ParentId":83095,
                  "UserSelected":false,
                  "UserHasAccess":false,
                  "Letter":null,
                  "IsVisible":true,
                  "InDepthLevel":0
               },
               {
                  "RetailerChilderen":[

                  ],
                  "Id":82370,
                  "Name":"Spar Hungary",
                  "HasInsightsCenter":false,
                  "ParentId":83095,
                  "UserSelected":false,
                  "UserHasAccess":false,
                  "Letter":null,
                  "IsVisible":true,
                  "InDepthLevel":0
               },
               {
                  "RetailerChilderen":[

                  ],
                  "Id":82374,
                  "Name":"Spar Croatia",
                  "HasInsightsCenter":false,
                  "ParentId":83095,
                  "UserSelected":false,
                  "UserHasAccess":false,
                  "Letter":null,
                  "IsVisible":true,
                  "InDepthLevel":0
               }
            ],
            "Id":83095,
            "Name":"SPAR ASPIAG",
            "HasInsightsCenter":false,
            "ParentId":648,
            "UserSelected":false,
            "UserHasAccess":false,
            "Letter":null,
            "IsVisible":true,
            "InDepthLevel":0
         }
      ],
      "Id":648,
      "Name":"Spar International",
      "HasInsightsCenter":true,
      "ParentId":0,
      "UserSelected":false,
      "UserHasAccess":false,
      "Letter":"S",
      "IsVisible":true,
      "InDepthLevel":0
   },
   {
      "RetailerChilderen":[

      ],
      "Id":860,
      "Name":"36.6 (Pharmacy)",
      "HasInsightsCenter":false,
      "ParentId":0,
      "UserSelected":false,
      "UserHasAccess":false,
      "Letter":"#",
      "IsVisible":true,
      "InDepthLevel":0
   },
   {
      "RetailerChilderen":[

      ],
      "Id":82926,
      "Name":"Ace Hardware Indonesia",
      "HasInsightsCenter":false,
      "ParentId":0,
      "UserSelected":false,
      "UserHasAccess":false,
      "Letter":"A",
      "IsVisible":true,
      "InDepthLevel":0
   }]
```

Right now in the code, I only loop through two levels and that is through the markup in Vue:

```
<ul class="item-container">
    <li v-for="item in retailers">

        <div class="item-info">
            <span>{{ item.Name }}</span>
        </div>

        <ul v-if="item.RetailerChilderen.length">
            <li v-for="subItem in item.RetailerChilderen">
                <div class="item-info">
                    <span>{{ subItem.Name }}</span>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
```

Wouuld using a Vue template that is generated by a method be the correct method to allow for multiple levels of nested JSON to be displayed in the DOM?

Comment: two functions 1) accessing a retailer 2) checking if it has sub retailer.. call the first function then another call from this to second... of this sort of approach would help you in this scenario

Comment: Might not be exact solution but sort of that approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a recursive component as you would with manipulating a node and its children.

```js
  const RetailerRec = Vue.component('RetailerRec', {
    props: ['retailer'],
    template: `
      <ul>
        <li> <input type="checkbox"/> {{retailer.Name}} </li>

        <template v-for="retailer in retailer.RetailerChilderen">
          <RetailerRec :retailer="retailer"/>
        </template>
      </ul>
    `
  })
  const tree = JSON.parse('[{"RetailerChilderen":[],"Id":83107,"Name":"10-11","HasInsightsCenter":true,"ParentId":0,"UserSelected":true,"UserHasAccess":true,"Letter":"#","IsVisible":true,"InDepthLevel":0},{"RetailerChilderen":[],"Id":82800,"Name":"1-800-Flowers.com","HasInsightsCenter":false,"ParentId":0,"UserSelected":true,"UserHasAccess":true,"Letter":"#","IsVisible":true,"InDepthLevel":0},{"RetailerChilderen":[{"RetailerChilderen":[{"RetailerChilderen":[],"Id":82371,"Name":"Hervis Sports","HasInsightsCenter":false,"ParentId":82247,"UserSelected":false,"UserHasAccess":false,"Letter":null,"IsVisible":true,"InDepthLevel":0}],"Id":82247,"Name":"Spar Austria","HasInsightsCenter":false,"ParentId":648,"UserSelected":false,"UserHasAccess":false,"Letter":null,"IsVisible":true,"InDepthLevel":0},{"RetailerChilderen":[{"RetailerChilderen":[],"Id":655,"Name":"Despar Italy","HasInsightsCenter":false,"ParentId":83095,"UserSelected":false,"UserHasAccess":false,"Letter":null,"IsVisible":true,"InDepthLevel":0},{"RetailerChilderen":[],"Id":82250,"Name":"Spar Slovenia","HasInsightsCenter":false,"ParentId":83095,"UserSelected":false,"UserHasAccess":false,"Letter":null,"IsVisible":true,"InDepthLevel":0},{"RetailerChilderen":[],"Id":82370,"Name":"Spar Hungary","HasInsightsCenter":false,"ParentId":83095,"UserSelected":false,"UserHasAccess":false,"Letter":null,"IsVisible":true,"InDepthLevel":0},{"RetailerChilderen":[],"Id":82374,"Name":"Spar Croatia","HasInsightsCenter":false,"ParentId":83095,"UserSelected":false,"UserHasAccess":false,"Letter":null,"IsVisible":true,"InDepthLevel":0}],"Id":83095,"Name":"SPAR ASPIAG","HasInsightsCenter":false,"ParentId":648,"UserSelected":false,"UserHasAccess":false,"Letter":null,"IsVisible":true,"InDepthLevel":0}],"Id":648,"Name":"Spar International","HasInsightsCenter":true,"ParentId":0,"UserSelected":false,"UserHasAccess":false,"Letter":"S","IsVisible":true,"InDepthLevel":0},{"RetailerChilderen":[],"Id":860,"Name":"36.6 (Pharmacy)","HasInsightsCenter":false,"ParentId":0,"UserSelected":false,"UserHasAccess":false,"Letter":"#","IsVisible":true,"InDepthLevel":0},{"RetailerChilderen":[],"Id":82926,"Name":"Ace Hardware Indonesia","HasInsightsCenter":false,"ParentId":0,"UserSelected":false,"UserHasAccess":false,"Letter":"A","IsVisible":true,"InDepthLevel":0}]')
  
  new Vue({
    components: { RetailerRec },
    data () {
      return { tree }
    },
    template: `<div>
      <RetailerRec v-for="retailer in tree" :retailer="retailer" :key="retailer.Id"/>
    </div>`,
    el: '#app'
  })
```

```css
li{
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: If the data from the JSON was being manipulated by another Vue component, how would we send it into RetailerRec?

Would we declare this Vue component inside of the other one so that the data was in scope?

Comment: Sorry I should clarify @grodzi , the JSON is stored in the data object inside of a separate Vue Instance. That JSON is manipulated by user actions. So how can I connect that data to this Vue component above?

Comment: First of all, in the json, the top level is not of a RetailerRec kind but is an array of RetailerRec kind, so you need a component to handle that (in snippet I handled that in the vue instance directly for simplicity). Once you do that component, likely it will accept the tree as props. When user modify that tree somewhere else, that component should just be refreshed "magically" with given tree props

Comment: So that data I'm using is called `filteredRetailers` and it's in a seperate Vue instance called MyInstance. You give the Vue component above the data of tree however I'm trying to understand how I can provide the data that's being used in the separate Vue instance instead.

Is there any way for me to provide that data to your RetailerRec component? I tried just changing the name from tree to filteredRetailers but it says it's not defined.

Comment: Ok I understood what you were saying, apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Create a component for one item and use it itself to create subitems in v-for.

Something like this:

Item.vue

```
<template>
  <li>
  <div class="item-info">
    <span>{{ item.Name }}</span>
  </div>
  <ul v-if="item.RetailerChilderen.length">
   <item v-for="(subItem, index) in item.RetailerChilderen" :item="subItem" :key="index" />
  </ul>
  <li>
</template>
```

Root.vue

```
<ul class="item-container">
    <item v-for="(item, index) in retailers" :item="item">
</ul>
```